# Android Sqlite INSERT error when table contains only _id

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite table that contains only the _id:

```
"create table rule (_id integer primary key);";
```

When running this set of commands:

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
mDb.insert(TABLE, null, initialValues)
```

I obtain the following exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO rule(null) VALUES (NULL)
```

The initial error occurs because ContentValues cannot be empty. Android provides a convenience parameter called nullColumnHack that allows you to pass a single column with the value null, to bypass this problem.

However this doesn't apply in my case because the row id (_id) cannot be null! Based on the syntax found in the [SQLite language docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html), I would like to be able to run the SQLite code:

```
INSERT INTO rule DEFAULT VALUES;
```

How can i achieve something like this using the android insert method? Or is there something I need to add to my create statement?

**UPDATE:** In the situation where a table contains ONLY a rowid, the proper syntax is to use INSERT INTO *_*_ DEFAULT VALUES.

The sqlite insert method listed in android does not support DEFAULT VALUES as an option.

[A bug has been filed with google](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20536) and to get support for default values the following commands would need to be executed:

```
mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO rule DEFAULT VALUES;");
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()",null);
c.moveToFirst();
int rowid = c.getInt(0);
```

As stated in the accepted answer, we can get around this (and DEFAULT VALUES) by using nullHackColumn and assigning the row id (_id) to null and letting SQLite make the conversion from null to the auto-incremented value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jeet mentioned you can provide `nullColumnHack` as a second parameter. And as you yourself mentioned `autoincrement` isn't necessary to increment a value of primary key.
So the syntax:

```
insert into rule (_id) values(null)
```

where _id is primary key and autoincremented value is correct for sql. I think most SQL databases will replace `null` with new incremented value, at least MySQL, SQLite and Oracle can do this

Thus:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
db.insert("rule", "_id", cv);
```

should give you desired results.

Comment: You are correct in the statement that "insert into rule (_id) values(null)" is valid SQL syntax. However this was one of the first attempts I tried before posting the question, because SQLite will throw an error because it does not swap out the value with the next value from autoincrement, as you suggested. Instead SQLite will actually try to assign _id the value NULL.

Comment: Just checked. I am able to insert a row with autoincremented value with provided code. It'll indeed try to assign NULL value on _id, but latter results in autoincrement as it's a primary key. What problems you're facing with this one?

Comment: You're right! When I tried this initially I passed cv as null and I believe that caused the problem. This is the correct syntax, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `autoincrement` to your create table query like:

```
"create table rule (_id integer primary key autoincrement);";
```

In your case you need to manually set the ID of the row with each insert. this way it will increment it automatically when you insert an empty row as you did in your case.

Comment: Actually, You don't have to specifically write AUTO_INCREMENT.
You just have to define the primary key as _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Ok, but in your contentvalues are not adding the id of the row, so i am assuming it should be automatically incremented. Also i am not seeing a reason why it shouldn't be autoincremented in this case. Why implement your own logic for setting ids rather than letting the database take care of that. the only reason why i wouldn't set the id to autoincrement would be if i was fetching my data from a service and i wanted a plain copy of that structure.

Comment: ContentValues cannot set the id of the row, simply because it does not know what the id is, without first querying the database and creating my own, poor autoincrement. I don't want to take this route.  Autoincrement is not necessary in the SQLite Syntax (see http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1). Autoincrement will work with the create table syntax provided in the original question, but the problem is that the INSERT method for android does NOT support default values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
ContentValues initialValues= new ContentValues();
if(check here --id is null----)
{
  initialValues.put("_id", "0");  
}
else
{
  initialValues.put("_id", id);  
}

mDb.insert(TABLE, null, initialValues)
```

Comment: Nope, E/SQLiteLog(936): (20) statement aborts at 6: [INSERT INTO rule(_id) VALUES (?)] datatype mismatch

Comment: as id is primary key so it cann't be null..can you go on to insert 0 for the values that are null??

Comment: Right, the id is the primary key, so it can't be null. By that same logic however, I can't just insert 0 as a value because that will only work for the first rule, when I need to create the second rule I would have to make the next row 1 and essentially create my own autoincrement.. And 0 would be bad since the database is 1-indexed not 0-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Check following:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

SQL doesn't allow inserting a completely empty row without naming at least one column name. If your provided values is empty, no column names are known and an empty row can't be inserted. If not set to null, the nullColumnHack parameter provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly insert a NULL into in the case where your values is empty.

Comment: Yes I saw this, but if we set nullColumnHack to _id (The row id) then the query will fail because the SQL that is generated is: INSERT INTO rule(_id) values NULL; Obviously this syntax isn't correct because we don't want to provide a value for _id but rather we want that value to be generated.

Comment: but why do you need a table having only column id. what purpose it can solve.

Comment: Rule is part of a larger database. Rule will contain the IDs of multiple types of Rules and is used as a foreign key for a many_to_many table "filter_rules".. RuleA and RuleB's primary key (rule_ptr) is a foreign key to the Rule table. This is used to prevent multiple many_to_many tables (i.e. filter_ruleA, filter_ruleB)

Answer (score 0):

the insert needs a null value you just have to put

```
db.insert ("people", null, c);
```